# Combine props from nested slots

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am using Vuetify 3 to display lists with child groups. When hovering over a line, a button should appears at the end of the line, which is realized with `v-hover`.

This works with regular `v-list-item`, but I also have nested lists through `v-list-group`, which comes with its own `activator` slot. Now both `v-hover` and the `activator` slot provide a `props` object that I need to bind to my nested content. So I need to merge them, but I don't know how.

//*tree.vue*

```
<template>
    <v-list density="compact" nav>
        <treeBranch :list="list" />
    </v-list>
</template>
```

//*treeBranch.vue*

```
<template>
    <template v-for="(item,i) in list" :key="item.title">
        <template v-if="item.childsCategory.length">
            <v-list-group subgroup fluid>
                <template v-slot:activator="{ props}">
                    <v-hover v-slot="{ isHovering, props }">
                        <v-list-item v-bind="props" :value="item.title">
                            <v-list-item-title >{{item.title}}</v-list-item-title>
                            <template v-slot:append>
                                <v-icon icon="$mdiInformationOutline"></v-icon>
                                <v-btn variant="text" size="small" icon="$mdiDotsVertical"
                                    :class="isHovering ? 'visible-btns': 'hidden-btns'"
                                ></v-btn>
                            </template>
                        </v-list-item>
                    </v-hover>
                </template>
                <treeBranch :list="item.childsCategory" :options="options"/>
            </v-list-group>
        </template>
        <template v-else>
            <v-hover v-slot="{ isHovering, props }">
                <v-list-item :value="item.title" density="compact" v-bind="props">
                    <v-list-item-title >{{item.title}}</v-list-item-title>
                    <template v-slot:append>
                        <v-icon icon="$mdiInformationOutline"></v-icon>
                        <v-btn variant="text" size="small" icon="$mdiDotsVertical" 
                            :class="isHovering ? 'visible-btns': 'hidden-btns'"
                        ></v-btn>
                    </template>
                </v-list-item>
            </v-hover>
        </template>
    </template>
</template>
```

I took all designs from here
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/hover/#hover-list
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#sub-group

Comment: Hey Dima, I tidied up your question a bit, let me know if I missed something

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new names for the props from `v-hover` and the `activator` slot:

```html
<template v-slot:activator="{ props: activatorProps}">
  <v-hover v-slot="{ isHovering, props: hoverProps }">
```

(the renaming is part of regular [destructuring assignement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment))

Now you can combine the props with spreading (`{...activatorProps, ...hoverProps}`) or `Object.assign(activatorProps, hoverProps)` and bind them:

```html
<v-list-item v-bind="{...activatorProps, ...hoverProps}">
```

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)